# MySQL group_concat in subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I have the query, below, which should work. But, MySQL is giving me the error message

> Subquery returns more than one row

```
SELECT e.episode_pk,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d.fulldescription separator ', ')
        FROM episode_rhythm er
        JOIN diagnosis d ON er.diagnosis_fk = d.diagnosis_pk 
        WHERE er.episode_fk = e.episode_pk
        GROUP BY d.fulldescription) as rhythmDesc 
FROM episode e  
WHERE e.patientid_fk = '89976';
```

The entire purpose of using the `GROUP_CONCAT` in this query is to return only one row per 'episode'.

The outer select returns multiple rows.
The inner `SELECT`, when run for a single episode table primary key, returns a single row as you would suspect:

```
SELECT group_concat(d.fulldescription separator ', ')
FROM episode_rhythm er
JOIN diagnosis d ON er.diagnosis_fk = d.diagnosis_pk 
WHERE er.episode_fk = 234776
GROUP BY d.fulldescription;
```

The inner `SELECT` without the `GROUP_CONCAT`, when run for a single episode table primary key, may return multiple rows:

```
SELECT d.fulldescription
FROM episode_rhythm er
JOIN diagnosis d ON er.diagnosis_fk = d.diagnosis_pk 
WHERE er.episode_fk = 234776;
```

What do I need to do to get this to work as I would expect?

Answer (score 4):

Your subquery within the SELECT is a bit doubtful.

I guess what you're looking for is:

```
SELECT
    e.episode_pk,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.fulldescription separator ', ')
FROM episode_rhythm er
JOIN diagnosis d ON er.diagnosis_fk = d.diagnosis_pk
JOIN episode e ON er.episode_fk = e.episode_pk
WHERE e.patientid_fk='89976' 
GROUP BY e.episode_pk
```